# How to stay connected to mqtt broker after I terminate my application (ios , Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, push, mqtt

I'm developing an app in swift using this source https://github.com/aciidb0mb3r/SwiftMQTT 
I want to add remote push notifications. I managed to do it with local notifications for example, when the app is running even if it's not in the foreground.

My question is how can i do it when the app isn't running. As i have seen when i close the app completed my broker say that i'm disconnected.
Is there any way to stay connected forever?

Something like remote push notifications that wake's up the application even if its not running

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can both use apple remote push notification and MQTT. When your app is not running, you can receive the notification using apple's APNs, and when the app is running, just use the MQTT and omit the apple's APNs.

Comment: You've already answered your own question. If you shut down the app it's going to disconnect, the only way to start it again is going to be a use Apple Push to wake it again.

Comment: thank you both for your answers! 
How can i wake it? and when it will be waked because if i want it to wake up i want it to be when it will receive a message but if its disconnected it will never wake up (or can i wake it up every 5 minutes connect and see if i have a message )

Comment: APN is well documented, go have a read and come back and ask a new questions if you get stuck

Comment: @hardillb thank you for your answer can you provide me a link for apn?

Comment: You can find documentation about Apple's notification system here: https://developer.apple.com/notifications/

Comment: @paulhauner thank you I will check it out. Happy new year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out what it should be.

Hivemq (a mqtt broker) has a [guide](http://www.hivemq.com/docs/plugins/1.4.0/#hivemqdocs_creating_your_first_plugin_project_using_intellij_idea) for developing a plugin with java, so that I did, I implemented push notification backend and with mysql connected clients  and when the message comes I search offline clients with the topic of message and send only to them the push!

Thanks all for your help.

Comment: Could you share your solution, how to send push notification even the the app is close.

Comment: Please Share your solution  . I need have please

Answer (score 0):

You can try using background fetch for periodical checking for messages.
Here is a useful tutorial for the different background modes ( it may be a bit outdated but the concepts are still valid ).

https://www.raywenderlich.com/143128/background-modes-tutorial-getting-started